# Какой в Python 3.6 есть аналог команде "cd" для смены рабочей директории из интерпретатора?

Tags: python

Я пробовал так:

```
cd C:/Users/Roma/rabota
cd "C:/Users/Roma/rabota"
cd ("C:/Users/Roma/rabota")
```

Но ни один из способов не сработал в интерпретаторе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне правильно сменить директорию из интерпретатора?

Comment: `cd` не является командой интерпретатора `python`. Сменить текущую директорию можно до входа в интерпретатор.

Answer (score 6):

Изменить рабочую директорию можно, например, так:

```
import os

os.chdir(path)
```

**Update:**

В случае с Windows есть два важных нюанса:

1. Путь необходимо обрамлять кавычками
2. Обратные слэши в пути к целевой папке необходимо дублировать

Т.е. конкретный пример для вашего случая становится таким:

```
import os

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Roma\\rabota")
```

**p.s.** за уточнение спасибо пользователю [`@tanatonaut`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16736/tanatonaut)

Comment: От себя добавлю, что в винде этот (path) надо обрамлять в кавычки ("path") ,  а также есть очень важный нюанс. 
Обратные слэши в пути к папке надо дублировать. То есть os.chdir("C:\\papka\\papka1")

Comment: @tanatonaut, спасибо, я обновил ответ и добавил в него ваше замечание

Comment: То что строку (путь к файлу) нужно заключать в кавычки - это не специфика Windows, это синтаксис Python. Если путь хранится в переменной, то имя переменной (очевидно) в кавычки заключать не нужно. Чтобы обратные слеши не экранировать, можно поставить `r` перед строкой: `r'C:\Users\Roma\rabota'`

Answer (score 2):

Читайте [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html):

```
os.chdir(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте **Python** в системную переменную, делается это так:

`ПКМ по Мой компьютер > Свойства > Дополнительные параметры системы > Переменные среды > Выбираете переменную Path > Изменить > Вставляете туда путь к Python`.

Готово

Теперь откройте терминал и перейдите в нужную директорию, к примеру `cd C://Users/User/Desktop` и после этого напишите в терминал `python`.  Теперь Вы в этой директории.

Вот и всё.

Comment: При установке Python на винде,есть опция настроить путь автоматически,так что не в этом у меня проблема.
Всё равно спасибо!